# Загрузить сертификат в Python

Tags: python, x509certificate

Дело в том что у меня есть кусок кода, который мне пригодится для подписи данных

но там уже используется каким то образом загруженный сертификат

```
key_raw = b64decode(cls.config.pem["KEY"])
cls._x509 = cls.config.pem["CERT"].strip()
```

у меня сертификат в формате x509  файл .cer, как его загрузить в питоне для использования в коде выше, есть догадки? :)

Comment: Можно весь код (ну понятное дело там, где вообще про сертификат)? А то так что-то мне не очень понятно...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Дальше в коде идет работа с данными в этих переменных, мне кажется особо не влияет, надо как то считать тот же pem["KEY"], в cls._x509 понятно наверно что можно загрузить чистый base64 сертификата

Comment: `print(cls.config.pem['KEY'])`

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica это кусок класса который уже работает с этими переменными, тут видимо сертификат и его ключ. У меня они не загружены. Отсюда вопрос вы знаете как в питоне считать файл .cer и получить его ключ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229385/python-open-with-cer-file-to-get-public-key-and-then-perform-verification